why my ball rig file not show in viewport after linked or append it?
As a beginner in blender, I downloaded a ball rig file to practice ball movement and bouncing. However, I am unable to linked or append it to the blender viewport. I am seeking guidance to solve this issue.
when i select all things blender is not working.

What is the extension of the filename and why are you trying to append it? If it's a '.blend' file, just use Blender's File > Open... menu.

Those aren’t objects, those are collections. That aside, you are saying that when you click the Append button, nothing happens?
